# Concatenation by using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to `CONCAT` between this on my `SELECT` statement in SQL Server.

All the columns are booleans.

The output will be like this if all of columns that are true

```
GGPNES
```

I tried to use this and it doesn't work

```
DECLARE @concat VARCHAR(40) ='';

SELECT
    Smoke, Invoice,
    Party, Summary,
    MySelf, Export,
    CASE
        WHEN MyTable.Smoke = 1 OR MyTable.Invoice = 1 
            THEN @concat + 'GG' 
        WHEN MyTable.Party = 1 
            THEN @concat + 'P'
        WHEN MyTable.Summary = 1 
            THEN @concat + 'N'
        WHEN MyTable.MySelf = 1 
            THEN @concat + 'E'
        WHEN MyTable.Export = 1 
            THEN @concat + 'S'
    END
FROM
    MyTable
```

Comment: Sample data and desired outcome would help clarify what you mean by doesn't work.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: And as SQL Server doesn't have a `boolean` datatype, I guess you mean `bit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want a concatenation of `CASE` expressions:

```sql
CASE WHEN Smoke = 1 OR Invoice = 1 THEN 'GG' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN Party = 1 THEN 'P' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN Summary = 1 THEN 'N' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN MySelf = 1 THEN 'E' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN Export = 1 THEN 'S' ELSE '' END
```